# Question in generated sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-sets

In measure theory, they say that,
$\mathcal{F(C)}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra generated by C.

And, 
(i) $\mathcal{F(C)} = \underset{\mathcal{C \subseteq P, \ P \ is \ a \ \sigma-algebra}}{\bigcap}$$\mathcal{P}$, 
(ii) $\mathcal{F(C)}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing C.

I'm having some conflicts in accepting it. Infact,
for example: 
Let, 
$X = \left\{ a,b,c,d,e \right\}$ 
$C = \left\{ a,b,c \right\}$

$\mathcal{F(C)} = \left\{\emptyset, X, \left\{ a \right\}, \left\{ b \right\}, \left\{ c \right\}, \left\{ a,b \right\}, \left\{ a,b,c \right\}, \left\{ a,c \right\}, \left\{ d,e \right\}, \left\{ a,b,d,e \right\}, \left\{ a,c,d,e \right\},\left\{ b,d,e\right\}, \left\{ c,d,e\right\}, \left\{ a,d,e \right\} , ...\right\}$ 
$\mathcal{F(\left\{ d, e \right\})} = \left\{ \emptyset, X, \left\{ d\right\}, \left\{ e\right\}, \left\{ d,e\right\}, \left\{a,b,c \right\}, \left\{ a,b,c,e \right\}, \left\{ a,b,c,d\right\} \right\}$

Clearly, $\mathcal{F(\left\{ d, e \right\})}$ contains less elements to that of $\mathcal{F(C)}$. 
But how is that possible since $\mathcal{F(C)} = \underset{\mathcal{C \subseteq P, \ P \ is \ a \ \sigma-algebra}}{\bigcap}$$\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{F(\left\{ d, e \right\})}$ is one of the $\mathcal{P}'s$?

Edit based on the comments of @ArturoMagidin: 
$C = \left\{ \left\{a\right\},\left\{b\right\},\left\{c\right\} \right\}$ (since $C$ should be the collections of subsets of $X$)

$\mathcal{F(C)} = \left\{\emptyset, X, \left\{ a \right\}, \left\{ b \right\}, \left\{ c \right\}, \left\{ a,b \right\}, \left\{ a,b,c \right\}, \left\{ a,c \right\}, \left\{ d,e \right\}, \left\{ a,b,d,e \right\}, \left\{ a,c,d,e \right\},\left\{ b,d,e\right\}, \left\{ c,d,e\right\}, \left\{ a,d,e \right\} , ...\right\}$

$\mathcal{F(\left\{ \left\{d\right\},\left\{e\right\} \right\})} = \left\{ \emptyset, X, \left\{ d\right\}, \left\{ e\right\}, \left\{ d,e\right\}, \left\{a,b,c \right\}, \left\{ a,b,c,e \right\}, \left\{ a,b,c,d\right\} \right\}$

Since $\mathcal{F(\left\{ \left\{d\right\},\left\{e\right\} \right\})}$ doesn't contain $C$, it's not one of intersecting $P's$.

Comment: $C$ is not a collection of subsets of $X$, so everything you are doing is nonsense. You need to start with a $C$ that is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, not a subset of $X$.

Comment: The smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that contains $C$ **as an element** is $\{\varnothing, X, C, X\setminus C\}$. The smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that contains $\{d,e\}$ as an element is $\{varnothing, X, \{d,e\}, X\setminus\{d,e\}\}$. The two are exactly the same: the four element $\sigma$-algebra $\{\varnothing, X, \{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain how come C is not a subset of X? Are you saying that $C$ should be $\left\{\left\{a\right\}, \left\{b\right\}, \left\{c\right\}\right\}$ ? 
And, if $K \in C$, then $K \in \mathcal{F(C)}$, isn't it?

Comment: Your $C$ **is** a subset of $X$, but what you need in the theorem is a *set of subsets* of $X$. $C$ is **not** a subset of $P(X)$, the power set of $X$. The theorem is about the $\sigma$ algebra generated by a **collection** of subsets. If you want to take $\mathcal{C}=\{ \{a,b,c\}\}$ (the set whose only element is the subset $\{a,b,c\}$, then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by *this* $\mathcal{C}$ is exactly what I stated it to be. If you take $\mathcal{C}=\{ \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}\}$, then  your issue disappears, since that is not a subset of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\{d\},\{e\}\}$.

Comment: Yes, each element of $\mathcal{C}$, *which will necessarily be a subset of $X$*, is in $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{C})$. But your $\{a,b,c\}$ is not a set of subsets of $X$. Its elements are **not** elements of any $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, since a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is, by definition, a collection of *subsets* of $X$, and none of $a$, $b$, or $c$ are subsets of $X$.

Comment: Now you've messed it up again. Still, your $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $X$. What the theorem needs is a **set of subsets** of $X$. That is the source of all your misundertandings here. Note that now, $\{a\}$ is an **element** of $X$, **not** a subset of $X$.

Comment: Okay, now you fixed that part, but your $\mathcal{F}(\{d,e\})$ is still nonsense. And if you change it to $\mathcal{F}(\{ \{d\},\{e\}\})$, then there is no longer a problem, because this $\sigma$-algebra does **not** contain any of $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, or $\{c\}$. Same if you take $\mathcal{F}(\{\{d,e\}\})$.

Comment: Again: $X$ is a set. The $\mathcal{C}$ from the theorem you are trying to understand needs to be a collection of subsets. Every **element** of $\mathcal{C}$ needs to be a **subset** of $X$.

Comment: Now your final sentence is false. Note that $\mathcal{F}(\{ \{d\},\{e\}\})$ does **not** contain $\mathcal{C}= \{ \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}\}$ as a subset, so it is **not** "one of the $\mathcal{P}$" being intersected. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{ \{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ consists precisely of all subsets of $X$ that either contain both $d$ and $e$, or neither. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\{d\},\{e\}\}$ consists precisely of the subsets of $X$ that either contain all three of $a$, $b$, and $c$, or contain none of them.

Comment: Understood your point now. Sorry for the numerous wrong attempts. I'm learning it with youtube and StackExchange as my guide. You saved me a lot of days of confusion. Saying thank you is not enough :)

Comment: (i) doesn't seem right. If $\mathcal P$ is any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal C$, then its intersection is empty. You probably meant to say that $\mathcal P$ is the set of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal C$.

Comment: @tomasz Thank you for commenting. Can you please explain how the intersection will be empty? Now that you're pointing it out, I'll try to make the question more clear.

Comment: If $\mathcal{X}$ is a collection of sets, the symbol $\cap \mathcal{X}$ means the intersection of the *elements* of $\mathcal{X}$ (which are sets). So if $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\bigcap\mathcal{P}$ means what you may denote as $$\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal{P}}A.$$ Since $\mathcal{P}$ contains $\varnothing$ as an element, the intersection is empty. What you mean is to take the intersection of all $\sigma$ algebras that contain $C$, $$\bigcap_{C\subseteq \mathcal{P},\mathcal{P}\text{ a }\sigma\text{-algebra}} \mathcal{P}.$$It's a notation issue.

Comment: But you shouldn't index it $i=1$ to $n$. There is no reason to think there are only finitely many such $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're right! Updated the question. Thanks for adding clarity.